# JavaScript: How to convert a for/of loop into a normal for loop with variables?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-of-loop

I have a code where I need to change a for/of loop into a normal for loop, but I don't know how to convert the variables. Such as if a have a

```
for (let sentence of sentences)
```

How do I change it to this structure?

```
for (var i = 0; i < .length; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
for (let i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
  console.log(sentences[i]); // it's your current sentence
}
```

**UPD**

How correctly noticed @FZs my code won't work on different types of iterables.

For transform iterator to array you can use `Array.from` method. I put link to MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: so where does my sentence variabel go? i need it further done in my code

Comment: @KarlaJensen You can access sentence like sentences[i]

Comment: @FZs You're absolutely right and I updated my answer